# Error reloading a QlikView document via commandline in a macro

Tags: vbscript, qlikview

I have an issue with reloading a QlikView document.  When I execute a batch file with the command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\QlikView\Qv.exe" /r "C:\QlikViewMount\reloadvictim.qvw"
```

the document reloads fine.

But, when I put it into a QlikView Macro (VBScript), it is giving me 'Unknown command line option'.
This is what I used:

```
strCommand = chr(34) & "C:\Program Files (x86)\QlikView\Qv.exe"  & chr(34) & "/r" & chr(34) & "C:\QlikViewMount\reloadvictim.qvw" & chr(34)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do, but is **chr(34)** what you want or do you wand **chr(32)** aka space?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23522117/603855 for background

Answer (score 0):

The syntax

```
 strCommand = chr(34) & " " ....
```

makes me think that you want to do a reload of your data when you are in [qlikview](/questions/tagged/qlikview).

Why not press *CTRL+R*?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your command line is missing a couple of spaces either side of your `/r` parameter, the below should solve your problem:

```
strCommand = chr(34) & "C:\Program Files (x86)\QlikView\Qv.exe" & chr(34) & " /r " & chr(34) & "C:\QlikViewMount\reloadvictim.qvw" & chr(34)
```