# VBS - Issue with quotes (beginning)

Tags: vbscript

```
strNewFolderName=%username%

oShell.run "cmd.exe /C NET SHARE strNewFolderName =""C:\test02\" & strNewFolderName & " "" /GRANT:" & strNewFolderName & ",FULL"
```

Kindly could you pleaes tell me where I forgot to type quotes ?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

you have extra quotes here `" "" /GRANT:"` are you trying to include quotes in the script? if so you could use & Chr(34) for extra quotes, see this [Link] ([Adding quotes to a string in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942554/vbscript-adding-quotes-to-a-string))

Answer (score 0):

First rule when using .Run or .Exec:

**Build the command into a variable and .Echo it.**

```
>> strNewFolderName = "NewFolderName"
>> sCmd = "cmd.exe /C NET SHARE strNewFolderName =""C:\test02\" & strNewFolderName & " "" /GRANT:" & strNewFol
derName & ",FULL"
>> WScript.Echo sCmd
>>
cmd.exe /C NET SHARE strNewFolderName ="C:\test02\NewFolderName " /GRANT:NewFolderName,FULL
```

Obviously, `strNewFolderName` was not interpolated/replaced, because VBScript does not automagically put variable content into string literals/you forgot to concatenate the first instance of `strNewFolderName` into the string.

Let's do the concatenation:

```
>> sCmd = "cmd.exe /C NET SHARE " & strNewFolderName & "=""C:\test02\" & strNewFolderName & " "" /GRANT:" & st
rNewFolderName & ",FULL"
>> WScript.Echo sCmd
>>
cmd.exe /C NET SHARE NewFolderName="C:\test02\NewFolderName " /GRANT:NewFolderName,FULL
```

Again it's obvious that there is a spurious space before the closing/second quote.

```
& " "" /GRANT:" &
```

should be

```
& """ /GRANT:" &
```

Second rule:

**Use the `.Echo`ed string to test your command from a console.**

Assuming this test succeeds, you then can use

```
oShell.Run sCmd
```

or - even better:

```
iRet = oShell.Run(sCmd, [intWindowStyle], [bWaitOnReturn])
```

with some confidence.

If you are willing to learn, you could look at

[How To Quote Like a Pro](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/fb.ashx?m=81189)

[Build your command in a more structured way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22481679/603855)